# Is there a program that can represent functions as sound?

Tags: software-rec, audio, mathematica

I need a program that can represent functions as sound. Something like Mathematica's "play" which can generate a sound with the amplitude given as a function of time.

The program should support "writing/exporting" to a lossless audio format.

*@soandos what I meant was a program that gives sound represntation of a mathmatical function "similar to how you plot functions"visualy""  Check Mathmatica for play to see what it does.*

Comment: By the way, please don't post [duplicates](http://superuser.com/questions/329807/i-need-a-program-that-can-represent-functions-as-sound) across the network, they'll be closed where they're off topic.

Comment: @ slhck : i didnt duplicate ,i asked the question on stackoverflow.com and some one told me to post it here so i posted it here beforei knew that they will migrate it to here.iam still knew after all and i didnt know that the 2 sites were connected

Comment: Just a friendly reminder. Sorry, those people told you to ask elsewhere and still migrated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [ChucK](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/) programming language.  It is made specifically for synthesizing audio.

Directly specifying the waveform as a function is not the typical way to work, but I believe it is also possible.

Answer (score 0):

Software synthesizers use functions such as *sine* or *random* in order to oscillate a parameter, e.g. the frequency cutoff of a filter or the volume of a sound source.

All synths implement the same predefined functions though, so you'd have to get one coded from scratch in order to be able to pass any given function to them.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of any programs that fulfill the requirements you are asking for.  However, long, long ago I wrote a similar program is Turbo Pascal as my final for my AP Comp Sci class in high school.  It took in basic mathematical functions and plotted them in a graph, and for fun I threw in a sound function as well.  If you cant find a program that does this, I dont think it would be hard for a programmer to throw one together.

BTW, most of the basic mathematical functions sound rather annoying in an electronic speaker beep.  Perhaps with modern sound cards and wave table synthesis it wouldnt sound so much like an scratching an electronic chalkboard.